# 'strcpy': _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS

Tags: c++

*****when I run this code ,I get some error.
'strcpy': ,'fscanf':,'fopen': _crt_secure_no_warnings 
how can I solve it?
**

else if ( (*root)->frequency > minHeap->array[0]. frequency )
    {

```
    minHeap->array[ 0 ]. root->indexMinHeap = -1;
    minHeap->array[ 0 ]. root = *root;
    minHeap->array[ 0 ]. root->indexMinHeap = 0;
    minHeap->array[ 0 ]. frequency = (*root)->frequency;

    // delete previously allocated memoory and
    delete [] minHeap->array[ 0 ]. word;
    minHeap->array[ 0 ]. word = new char [strlen( word ) + 1];
    strcpy( minHeap->array[ 0 ]. word, word );

    minHeapify ( minHeap, 0 );
}
```

}

fscanf:

```
void printKMostFreq(FILE* fp, int k)
```

{

```
MinHeap* minHeap = createMinHeap(k);

// Create an empty Trie
TrieNode* root = NULL;

// A buffer to store one word at a time
char buffer[MAX_WORD_SIZE];

// Read words one by one from file.  Insert the word in Trie and Min Heap
while (fscanf(fp, "%s", buffer) != EOF)
    insertTrieAndHeap(buffer, &root, minHeap);

// The Min Heap will have the k most frequent words, so print Min Heap nodes
displayMinHeap(minHeap);
```

}

fopen:

```
int main(){
int k = 5;
FILE *fp = fopen("file.txt", "r");
if (fp == NULL)
    printf("File doesn't exist ");
else
    printKMostFreq(fp, k);
return 0;
```

}

Comment: *"'strcpy': ,'fscanf':,'fopen': _crt_secure_no_warnings"* - That's the error message? Really? Which compiler?

Comment: Why are you using C "strings" in a C++ program in the first place?

Comment: "FILE *fp = fopen("file.txt", "r");" - prefer [fstream](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/fstream) in C++. In fact, most of your code looks like C compiled with a C++ compiler interspaced with a bit of old-style (pre-C++11) C++. You would do yourself a favour by reading up on modern C++ - there are better ways to do most things you are doing.

Comment: how to copy 2 string string data type , c++ without using strcpy @JesperJuhl

Comment: @C.Dogan You can construct a [std::string](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string) directly [from a const char*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string) (see nr. 5).

Answer (score 1):

It is a warning in msvc which is telling you the functions are a bit more risky than others.

You can suppress it by adding **_crt_secure_no_warnings** to the preprocessor settings in the project properties.